# Try to create similar to preexisting javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a similar javascript function to the loadAllOriginal.
But the value of the variable allEmployees is a list with emplooyee objects(ID,FirstName,LastName).How can I do that?
I am trying to use this method with the autocomplete  from this page:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

```
function loadAllOriginal() 
{
    var allEmployees = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California,   Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
  Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
  Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
  Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
  North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
  South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
  Wisconsin, Wyoming';

    return allEmployees.split(/, +/g).map(function (employee) 
    {
        return 
        {
            value: employee.toLowerCase(),
            display: employee
        };
    });
}

function loadAll()
{
    var allEmployees = $http.post('../Admin/GetUsers/');
    ..........
}
```

Comment: Similar how exactly? Are you asking how to get the employes from the first function, which should be straight forward seeing as it returns those employes when you call it ?

Comment: The bottom function loadAll needs to do the same like the loadAllOriginal.

Comment: What is the structure of the data received via the post request? JSON?

Comment: you are not providing enough information for anyone to accurately answer this question. you show an array of states (employees) and then ask us to produce the id's for each one. how on earth do you expect us to do that when we have no idea what the ids are or where they come from? please fix your question..

Comment: The structure of the data received is  list with emplooyee objects(ID,FirstName,LastName)

Comment: There is no way that `loadAll` can behave the same `loadAllOriginal` since `loadAll` is an async function. You need to be handling the result of $post in a then function of the promise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so I made a bad assumption that you knew how to get the records loaded into the allEmployees variable. I have updated my answer to include how to get data from an asynchronous function call and then subsequently be able to use that data.

One way that you can get this to work is by using a deferred object and returning a promise from your loadAll() function. This can be done using the $q service that is built into angular. Here is one way to implement it:

```
function loadAll() {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        $http.post('../Admin/GetUsers/').then(function successCallback(response) {
            resolve(response.data.map(function (employee, index) {
                return {
                    value: employee.ID,
                    display: employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName
                }
            }));
        }, function failureCallback(response) {
            reject("Error!");
        });
    });
}
var allEmployees = [];
loadAll().then(function success(employees) {
    allEmployees = employees;
}, function failure(message) {
    console.log(message);
    allEmployees = [];
}).then(function (){
    console.log(allEmployees);
    // rest of your code that uses the allEmployees variable goes here...
});
```

Comment: Thank you . I am getting the following error: "TypeError: allEmployees.map is not a function"

Comment: Don't just hand out code with no explanation. Also, `$http.post` is asynchronous and does not return an array.

Comment: This isn't going to work as the call is async and won't return something straight away. In fact, it might not return anything at all

Comment: Meh, I guess I was assuming that the OP knew how to get results from the AJAX method because in the question it stated that "allEmployees is a list of objects(ID, FirstName, LastName)...", I was more-so demonstrating how to map it into the data structure they needed returned. I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I modified my question and explained how I am trying to use this method

Comment: @MikeC I have updated the answer to include the handling of the async function

Comment: @putvande I have updated the answer to include the handling of the async function